# Best way of writing tests with lots of stages

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

So I'm trying to write out a test for our case flows as gradually we have made them more end to end finding spots to split out the tests to avoid hitting limitations is getting harder and harder. I know we get double the allowance but over multiple objects with multiple stages each all dependant on the parents and children I seem to be drifting closer and closer to these limits. One thought I had as a possible solution is there any way of inserting/updating data "as is" not triggering any triggers?

Comment: If they are your triggers, do code in a big on/off switch that your tests can then set. Such a switch can also be useful for e.g. data migrations and other situations. (Unfortunately the platform doesn't have such a mechanism build in.)

Comment: Alternatively, again if these are your triggers, if you've used best practice where you have trigger handlers with non-static methods and some form of dependency injection to allow the trigger handler implementation used to be controlled, you can ensure that your tests override the trigger handlers with no-op implementations.

Comment: Are you using an `@testSetup` annotated method to create and insert your test data? If so, are you using `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` in it? We can use start/stop test in an `@testSetup` method and still use start/stop test in individual test methods.

Comment: @DerekF So this would again double my limitations effectively? I could use `@testsetup` to do the generics then the same again in the actual test class?

Comment: @PhilW the main issue I have is it's not just apex triggers it's flows and process builders

Comment: @KarlLivesey Yes, though you'll get 3x the limit instead of 4x (start/stop test in `@testSetup` = 1x, 1x in your test method, 1x again for start/stop test in your test method). Any limits used in an `@testSetup` method outside of start/stop test count towards the normal limits of each test method.

Comment: @DerekF I'll take what I can get but still the ideal would be a disable all automations button so I can disable flows/apex/processes so I can import prepared starting points.